# Key in Davinci / Motion track in Blender

Tags: tracking, chromakey

I am editing something in Davinci Resolve - but I am trying to do the motion tracking in Blender.  I have gotten the tracking to work in Blender on the main footage that has been filmed, now I want to move the tracking to a new video (which is the background for the main project file) - how do I move the tracking data from one video to another?

Comment: So your issue is not DaVinci/Blender file exchange, but you have an issue to Motion Track in Blender. To let us help you would have to share your file with at least 10 frames of video (or image sequence) source

Answer (score 0):

The footage you use for tracking and footage you use in compositing can be totally independent, so you can use the raw footage to do the tracking in Blender and then import the already keyed footage to do the compositing.

Comment: You don't have to transfer tracking data from one video to another. Once you've done the tracking you have a 3D scene with an animated camera. If the keyed video is exactly the same footage just with the keying done, you can just use that in compositing as a background.

Or maybe I didin't understand exactly what you're trying to do. Can you give more details? Are you trying to add a 3D object to a scene? What is the final effect you're trying to achieve?

Comment: So you do the motion tracking using the raw footage, then you'll have an animated camera that has the tracked movement. Then you can use that camera to render whatever background you want and the movement will match your original footage.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You don't 'move the tracking data' from one video to another. The tracking data isn't in any particular video. You got the tracking data from one video and generated an animated camera from that data. Now you have a camera with animation that matches the tracked footage and you can do whatever you want with it, you can place anything you want in your scene, render and then composite it.
I still don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but it seems like you want to skip straight to compositing.

Comment: Maybe I could help more if you explained what the scene is and what you're trying to remove or replace in that scene.

Comment: I'd render the new background with the camera that has the tracking animation, then I'd comp the keyed footage of the 2 guys at a desk on top of that render. That can be done in another compositing software, like After Effects, or it can be done directly in Blender in the compositor panel.

Comment: https://youtu.be/YjJFppadSlE
This tutorial might be useful

Comment: Please ... @Edward if you have more useful info (to make your Q clear) than rewrite your Question via edit. Alexandre if newly formed question will be clear for you please edit your answer instead of another comment. Chatting is not allowed here ...so if it is possible to delete comments here, it would appreciated :) Thank you keep this site organised.